# display errors each one

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a form to change the password, I should enter an old password and a new password to change the password using ajax jquery like below

```js
error: function (reject, error) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(reject.responseText);
    //alert(response.errors.password[0]);
    var error_old_pass = response.errors.old_password[0];
    var error = response.errors.password[0];
    //alert(error);
    $('#password_icon').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#password_icon').attr('class', 'fas fa-exclamation-triangle');
    if (error_old_pass)
        $('#old_password_error').find('strong').html(error_old_pass);
    if (error)
        $('#password_error').find('strong').html(error);
```

the problem is if I entered the old password incorrectly the hint doesn't appear(The password is incorrect.). and if I entered the correct old password and the new password incorrectly the hint for the new password doesn't appear"Password at least 8 characters."
if I entered the old password incorrectly and the new password less than 8 characters the two hints appears

Comment: you can use jquery validation instead of this

Comment: I used laravel controller

Comment: https://codingdriver.com/ajax-jquery-form-validation-in-laravel-7.html   follow this url